# Were houses ever built with the perimeter tile connectind to the basement floor drain and trap to flow to city sewer line?

Tags: plumbing

While having the floor drain w/ trap replaced in the basement of the house built in 1968, a pipe which I was told was part of the perimeter tile was discovered connected to the drain pipe and is now illegal to reconnect. Can it be capped  off.

Comment: Does the tile have another way to drain(sump pump pit, slope outside)?  The section going to the sewer will need capping or moving to another drain way.

Comment: The answer to your titular question is obviously "Yes" because yours was. Was it legal when done? Maybe. Is it legal now? Obviously not. What is it, exactly that you're looking to cap? The drain tile? If so, you'll get it full of water with no place to go and stagnant water is a _great_ breeding ground for mosquitoes...

Comment: I think my old house was the same way, back when I was putting stuff into outlets.